# Determine %Variance between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, compare

I have 2 data frames, for example:

df1:

```
      REF            Date                 Value  
0     REF1           01/09/2022 00:00     15985.50
1     REF1           01/09/2022 00:00     15968.00
2     REF1           01/09/2022 00:00     15991.00
3     REF2           01/09/2022 00:00     15908.50
4     REF2           01/09/2022 00:00     16010.50
```

df2:

```
      REF            Date                 Value 
0     REF1           01/10/2022 00:00     15985.50           
1     REF1           01/10/2022 00:00     15968.00          
2     REF1           01/10/2022 00:00     15991.00           
3     REF2           01/10/2022 00:00     15908.50            
4     REF2           01/10/2022 00:00     16110.50
```

I need to compare the sum of each REF/Value to determine the % variance from September to October so that result looks like:

```
REF1 0%
REF2 0.31%
```

I have been able to return a result for one reference at a time, using the code below;

```
df1['total_variance'] = np.where(df1['value'] == df2['value'], 0, df1['value'] - df2['value'])
```

But I need to run thousands of references through at a time!

Comment: Are these [tag:pandas] dataframes? If so, please add that tag to your question. Please also see [formatting help](/help/formatting) for instructions on how to format your questions using StackOverflow's flavor of markdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that you want to do something to *groups* of rows, where each group is a single `REF*`. This should tell you [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) is something you might be able to use.

```
grps1 = df1.groupby("REF")
grps2 = df2.groupby("REF")
```

Next, you want the *sum* of each group. Conveniently, `.groupby` returns a `GroupBy` object, which has a [`.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) method!

```
sum1 = grps1.sum()
sum2 = grps2.sum()

print("sum1:")
print(sum1)

print("sum2:")
print(sum2)
```

```
sum1:
        Value
REF          
REF1  47944.5
REF2  31919.0

sum2:
        Value
REF          
REF1  47944.5
REF2  32019.0
```

Now, it's easy to find the % variance. Since the index of `sum1` and `sum2` are the values of `REF*` for that group, simply subtracting them will subtract the corresponding `REF*`s:

```
pctvariance = (sum2 - sum1) / sum1 * 100
```

which gives:

```
         Value
REF           
REF1  0.000000
REF2  0.313293
```

Comment: thanks that has worked a treat!

Comment: Glad to help! Remember to upvote answers that are helpful, and accept an answer that you feel answers your question. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](/help/someone-answers) @Ryan1234